# Algorithm for efficient way to search and consolidate object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I have built an application with NodeJS we have a functionality of upload contact sheet and merge contacts.

There are 2 match conditions

> Contact should be merge based on phone numbers or email address. If
> any phone number or email should match then the contact should
> consider as an existing/duplicate contact and merge with search
> object.

CSV contacts compare throughout all database contacts of the user.

> For eg:
>
> if a user has 1000 contacts in his DB and now he may upload
> 5000 contacts via csv then every csv contact row object should match
> with database contact object.
>
> it traverse total 1000 ( contact
> rows of DB ) * 5000 (contact rows of CSV) = 5000000 Total traversals.

It pretty much expensive at this moment what I have implemented in my application. I want an efficient way of searching and merging contacts without fail to check duplicate contact conditions.

> **Scenario:**

There is a scenario I post here.

> **Phone contacts**
> [{id: 1, name: 'Kyle Brook', phones: [1234567890]}]
>
> **CSV:**
> [{name: 'Kyle Brooks', emails: ['kylebrooks@test.com', 'kylebrooks12@test.com'], phones: [1234567890]}
> {name: nulll, emails: ['kylebrooks@test.com'], phones: [1234567890, 0987654321]}]
>
> **Final Result:**
> [{name: 'Kyle Brooks', emails: ['kylebrooks@test.com', 'kylebrooks12@test.com'], phones: [1234567890,0987654321]}]

I did a code which may take appx. 154589 ms to execute code for 5000000 Total traversals.

A review below code link I require to post whole code otherwise it can't possible to get an idea about code.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/dipakchavda2912/eua1truj/`
```

Comment: *I did a code which may take*, can you show us?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Code please.....

Comment: @GandalftheWhite Sure I shall update in few minutes

Comment: @GandalftheWhite please review now

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to proceed and it can depend of your contact database.

Try to use your database and its indexe engine if you can. Walk through your CVS contact and request the database to find a duplicate contact.

Database are design to store, retrieve and proceed data. It's its job.

Comment: I required an efficient algorithm to traverse data.